# Does a linear transformation of Gaussian copula dependent variables result in independent variables?

Tags: probability

We know that for the multivariate normal variables X, the linear transformation $Z=A^{-1}X$ will give independent variables, where $AA^{T}=P$ and P is the correlation matrix.

I was wondering if any variant of Gaussian copula may have the similar property that allows the linearly transformed variables to be independent.